# Install unohelper on virtual env

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, openoffice.org, uno

What's the command for installing `unohelper` via pip?

I tried `$ pip install unotools`, but it doesn't work.
I have `uno` and `unotools` installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unotools:

> sudo aptitude install -y libreoffice libreoffice-script-provider-python uno-libs3 python3-uno python3

To test it:

```
python3
import uno
import unohelper
```